# What's a naming convention for typedefing blocks?

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions, objective-c-blocks, typedef

I'm declaring a lot of block types with typedef; is there any sort of naming convention for them?

Comment: Did you find a solution/answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>See here in Apple's documentation, [Enumerated constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-1002854) and [Naming Properties and Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE)</del>

I can't really find anything in Apple's documenation, but I did fins one from [AppCelerator](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/guide/Objective-C_and_Objective-C++_Coding_Standards-section-30088343_Objective-CandObjective-C++CodingStandards-Blocks).

Comment: I don't quite understand; what enumerated constants have to do with blocks?

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bunch of research, it seems that Apple doesn't typedef their blocks, and prefers to just name the parameters explicitly where they are used. Their Cocoa style guide also makes no mention of blocks being typedef'd.

For example, look at this method in NSURLSession.h from the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
                     willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
                                     newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                              completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest * _Nullable))completionHandler;
```

Note that the completionHandler doesn't receive a typedef.

In my opinion, it only makes sense to typedef a block if the definition is immediately reusable, and is generic enough to be used in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

from [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html) it's CamelCase with objective-C naming convention style (explicit/verbose)

Comment: The page you link to doesn't address the naming convention of blocks in objective-c; It does, however, give example on how to write blocks. Could you add a link for the naming convention?

Comment: from the doc : "typedef float (^MyBlockType)(float, float);", from programming with objective-C : "typedef void (^XYZSimpleBlock)(void);" I don't think they need to be more explicit :)

Comment: I agree, its a good example of how to write it... that does not mean it is a naming convention. Apple doesn't seem to have a naming convention for just blocks. Most likely due to that block consist (amongst others) of variables, constants and classes which all have their own naming convention; hence I do not believe Apple finds it important enough to write a separate convention for Blocks.

Comment: Indeed, you will find a lot of C-style typedef my_block or myBlock with lower camel case all over the internet :)